# How can I add string components to an integer for an if statement?

Tags: java, if-statement

I am currently making an `if` statement, but in that if statement I need to add string character, so based on what you say it either takes away 4 or not.

```
public static void yesornodisability()
{
    String disabled;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Are you registered disabled(Yes / No)? ");
    disabled = scanner.nextLine();
    return;
}
```

This is the method I am using for my string, When I run the top code (yesornodisability) it works. However when I run the second code it gives me an error saying void cannot be converted to java.lang.String.

This is my if statement

```
public static int swimmingprice()
 {
     int userAge = age();
     int totalCost = total();
     String disabled = yesornodisability();
        
     if (userAge<=18)
     {
         totalCost= totalCost/2;
     }
     else if(userAge>=65)
     {
         totalCost = totalCost-3;
     }
     else if(disabled.equals("Yes"))
     {
         totalCost = totalCost-4;
     }
     else
     {
         totalCost = 10;
     }
     
     System.out.println("The swimming price for you is "+totalCost+" pounds.");
     return swimmingprice();
 }
```

Comment: You method signature for `yesornodisability()` returns void.  You need to change the return type to `String` and then return the `disabled` variable.

Comment: `yesornodisability()` has a void return type and isn't returning anything.  It's not enough to just read the value in the function, you have to return it too.

Comment: Also be aware of the integer division.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void yesornodisability()
{
    String disabled;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Are you registered disabled(Yes / No)? ");
    disabled = scanner.nextLine();
    return;
}
```

You need to get rid of the void and return disabled.

```
return disabled;
```

You also need to fix your what your returning in the swimmingPrice() method.

```
return totalCost;
```

Instead of `System.out.println("The swimming price for you is "+totalCost+" pounds."); return swimmingprice();`

Change to `return "The swimming price for you is " + totalCost + "pounds."`
Then in the main method `System.out.println(swimmingPrice());`

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you need to change your method's return type and return the value from it.

Here is fixed code for you.

```
public static String yesornodisability()
{
    String disabled;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Are you registered disabled(Yes / No)? ");
    disabled = scanner.nextLine();
    return disabled;
}
```